# Display commands of one namespace in symfony2

Tags: php, symfony

Is there a way to display all commands of only one namespace? all commands of only doctrine for instance?

It'd be really nice since I have a lot of commands and a lot of command namespaces .

> I do know `| grep <namespace>` but looking for a built-in symfony option if it exists
>
> Given that I'm using symfony2.0

Comment: You edited right as I posted about `grep`. I don't believe there's a built-in option, likely because `grep` is so easy and readily available.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Enter only the beginning of the namespace to list the available commands:

```
$ php app/console doctrine

  [InvalidArgumentException]               
  Command "doctrine" is not defined.       
  Did you mean one of these?               
      doctrine:query:sql                   
      doctrine:query:dql                   
      doctrine:schema:drop                 
      doctrine:mapping:info                
      […]
```

But it won't display all the commands if the number is low:

```
$ php app/console doctrine:cache
  [InvalidArgumentException]                                                                                   
  Command "doctrine:cache" is ambiguous (doctrine:cache:clear-result, doctrine:cache:clear-query and 1 more).
```

The `list` command can also be used, it will sort the commands and add a description:

```
$ php app/console list doctrine
Symfony version 2.3.28 - app/dev/debug

Usage:
  command [options] [arguments]

Options:
  --help           -h Display this help message
  […]

Available commands for the "doctrine" namespace:
  doctrine:cache:clear-metadata         Clears all metadata cache for an entity manager
  doctrine:cache:clear-query            Clears all query cache for an entity manager
  doctrine:cache:clear-result           Clears result cache for an entity manager
  doctrine:database:create              Creates the configured databases
  doctrine:database:drop                Drops the configured databases
  doctrine:ensure-production-settings   Verify that Doctrine is properly configured for a production environment.
  […]
  doctrine:schema:create                Executes (or dumps) the SQL needed to generate the database schema
  doctrine:schema:drop                  Executes (or dumps) the SQL needed to drop the current database schema
  doctrine:schema:update                Executes (or dumps) the SQL needed to update the database schema to match the current mapping metadata
  doctrine:schema:validate              Validates the doctrine mapping files

$ php app/console list doctrine:cache
Symfony version 2.3.28 - app/dev/debug

[…]

Available commands for the "doctrine:cache" namespace:
  doctrine:cache:clear-metadata   Clears all metadata cache for an entity manager
  doctrine:cache:clear-query      Clears all query cache for an entity manager
  doctrine:cache:clear-result     Clears result cache for an entity manager
```

Comment: :D this does work but not for symfony2.0 :/, guess I have to use `grep`

Comment: Consider upgrading to 2.3, or 2.7.  Your version is pretty old

Comment: @smarber it works with Symfony 2.3.28 and 2.6.7, but I'm not sure this is the expected behaviour because it displays the help block every time...